# Yup start_date strictly before end_date validation

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, yup

How to validate a start_date that must be before_end, without equality to be true ?

I have this schema :

```
start_date: yup
      .date()
      .typeError("Wrong type")
      .required("required")
      .less(
        yup.ref("end_date"),
        "Start must be before end",
      ),
    end_date: yup
      .date()
      .nullable()
      .typeError("Wrong type")
      .min(
        yup.ref("start_date"),
        "Start must be before end",
      )
```

But doing this, if both dates are equal, it pass